# best way to validate a user's upload files in django

Tags: python, django

What is the best way to validate a user's upload files, both in size and type?

Comment: Is this an internal site where you trust your users? Open it based on extension. Is it something from that wretched hive of scum and villainy called the internet? There may be a scan tool that you could use on the command line

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_file_size(value):
    filesize= value.size
    
    if filesize > 10485760:
        raise ValidationError("The maximum file size that can be uploaded is 10MB")
    else:
        return value



class File(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    filepath= models.FileField(upload_to='files/', verbose_name="", validators=[validate_file_size])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.filepath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the file mimetype and its suffix. For example:

```
from pathlib import Path
from django.conf import settings

def file_validator(value):
    if value.size > settings.MAX_FILE_SIZE:
        raise ValidationError("File is too big.")
    if not Path(str(value)).suffix.strip().lower() in ["list of strings of valid suffix"]:
        raise ValidationError("File does not look like as ....")
    mime_type = mimetypes.guess_type(str(value))[0]
    if mime_type not in ["list of strings of valid mime types"]: # image/png, image/jpeg and etc
        raise ValidationError("Invalid mime type.")
```